# How to redirect after mail is sent with PHPMailer for multiple forms?

Tags: php, html, forms, phpmailer

I have a Php form and PHP mailer to shoot email but I want to add a redirection after successful mail sent. Tried multiple codes from the internet but none of them working. Also like I have 5-6 different forms with the same Php mailer. so please suggest me how to redirect them on different pages. Below I am sharing the form code and mailer code.

The Below Form is placed on "https://www.dignitysoft.com/contact-us.php" and wants it to redirect after successful email shoot to "https://www.dignitysoft.com/thank-you.php".

Tried multiple codes from the internet but none of them was worked.

```
<form class="email_form" method="post">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <div class="form-group customised-formgroup">
                                      <span class="icon-user"></span>
                                        <input type="text" name="full_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <div class="form-group customised-formgroup">
                                        <span class="icon-envelope"></span>
                                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <div class="form-group customised-formgroup">
                                        <span class="icon-telephone"></span>
                                        <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <div class="form-group customised-formgroup">
                                        <span class="icon-laptop"></span>
                                        <input type="text" name="website" class="form-control" placeholder="Website">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="form-group customised-formgroup">
                                        <span class="icon-bubble"></span>
                                        <textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn-wrapper">
                                <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-fill">Contact us now!</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

```
<?php

$name = trim($_POST['full_name']);
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$phone = trim($_POST['phone']);
$website = trim($_POST['website']);
$_message = trim($_POST['message']);
if ($name == "") {
    $msg['err'] = "\n Full name can not be empty!";
    $msg['field'] = "full_name";
    $msg['code'] = FALSE;
} else if ($email == "") {
    $msg['err'] = "\n Email can not be empty!";
    $msg['field'] = "Email";
    $msg['field'] = "email";
    $msg['code'] = FALSE;
} else if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
    $msg['err'] = "\n Please put a valid email address!";
    $msg['field'] = "email";
    $msg['code'] = FALSE;
} else if ($phone == "") {
    $msg['err'] = "\n Phone number can not be empty!";
    $msg['field'] = "phone";
    $msg['code'] = FALSE;
} else if (!preg_match("/^\(?\+?([0-9]{1,4})\)?[-\. ]?(\d{3})[-\. ]?([0-9]{3})$/", trim($phone))) {
    $msg['err'] = "\n Please put a valid phone number!";
    $msg['field'] = "phone";
    $msg['code'] = FALSE;
}  else if ($_message == "") {
    $msg['err'] = "\n Message can not be empty!";
    $msg['field'] = "message";
    $msg['code'] = FALSE;
} else {
    $to = 'xyz@domain.com';
    $subject = 'Contact Query';
    $message = '<html><head></head><body>';
    $message .= '<p>Name: ' . $name . '</p>';
    $message .= '<p>Email: ' . $email . '</p>';
    $message .= '<p>Phone: ' . $phone . '</p>';
    $message .= '<p>Website: ' . $website . '</p>';
    $message .= '<p>Message: ' . $_message . '</p>';
    $message .= '</body></html>';

    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From:  XYZ <xyz@domain.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'cc: ' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'bcc: ' . "\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, '-f xyz@domain.com');

    $msg['success'] = "\n Your Email has been sent successfully";
    $msg['code'] = TRUE;
}
echo json_encode($msg);
```

I just want all forms to redirect different thankyou pages for goal tracking.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can redirect like this:

```
header("Location: thank-you.php");
```

In Javascript you can redirect like this:

```
window.location.href = '/thank-you.php';
```

If you want to do something on the page after the email is sent, but before the redirect, then you need to redirect via JS. Otherwise you can redirect via PHP. Since you have different forms and you want to redirect to different thank you pages, you could specify that in the backend, based on the kind of form which was sent.

Answer (score 0):

you can use header location to redirect in php and use query string to send data back

```
 if(mail()) {
          header('Location: http://example.com?success='.$msg['success']);
        } else {
          echo 'Message was not sent.';
        }
```

On Thank you page just use below code to get message value

```
if (isset($_GET['success'])) {    
   echo $_GET['success'];
}
```

you can Also use sessions to send data across php pages.